# Compiling boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp on macosx works on linux

Tags: c++, macos, boost, ssl

server.cpp - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp

I am trying to build this on my mac. Using the following. (builds fine on my ubuntu system)

```
g++ -I /usr/local/boost/  sslserver.cpp -o sslserver -lboost_system -lssl -lpthread
```

My libs are located in /usr/local/lib so I tried adding -L /usr/local/lib after the includes. However, I have built other projects before using -lboost_system -lpthread without any issues or specifying the libs.

The error is huge > https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15586644/error.txt

Its mainly lots of deprecated methods warnings - I doubt anything is deprecated.
followed by Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64.

How should I go about building server.cpp on MacOSX?

Comment: This is probably not the problem, but you should use -L /usr/local instead of /usr/local/lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See 
 - [Why is Apple Deprecating OpenSSL in MacOS 10.7 (Lion)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406946/why-is-apple-deprecating-openssl-in-macos-10-7-lion)

Apple is migrating from OpenSSL to Common Crypto, hence depreciated warnings

Comment: They are just warnings. The error is about the build architecture care to shed any light on this?

Comment: My answer was only about the warnings you were receiving, apologies