# No OpenSSL Support Error When Compiling

Tags: xcode, multithreading, compiler-errors, openssl, static-libraries

With the recent removal of OpenSSL in Xcode 7, I find myself having to build the library manually for an older program that utilizes it. I've got an Xcode project that purportedly builds the library (libcrypto.a and libssl.a are successfully created), but when compiling the older program, I get the error:

"no OpenSSL thread support"

This is caused by a preprocessor check throwing the error:

```
...

    #define OPENSSL_THREAD_DEFINES
    #include <openssl/opensslconf.h>

    #ifndef OPENSSL_THREADS
    #error no OpenSSL thread support
    #endif

...
```

The opensslconf.h file is being found, but apparently OPENSSL_THREADS is not being defined it it. Is this supposed to be included somewhere in that file? Is it some sort of configuration error on my part when building the OpenSSL library?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: OpenSSL has not been supplied by Apple for several years, 2011. See this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7406994/451475) for more information. Basically it was dropped because thereleases had many issues with backward compatibility and that caused compile errors when devs updated.

Comment: It was deprecated, but still supported until the recent Xcode 7 release. Regardless, this doesn't help me solve my issue.

Comment: Look at CocoaPods for [OpenSSL](https://cocoapods.org/?q=OpenSSL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers was found in one of the options you can use when configuring  the build for OpenSSL and Curl respectively:

```
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc
```

and

```
./configure --with-darwinssl
```